# multidimensional array in java trying to implement an adjacency matrix

Tags: arrays, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to implement an adjacency matrix using a multidimensional array but i keep getting an error in eclipse when i write the for loop can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
 public class Graph_arr
            {
              int row  = 6 ;
              int column = 6;
              int [][] member = new int [row][column];
              for(int i=0 ;i < row; i ++)
                  {
                  for (int j = 0 ; j < column ;j++)
                       {
                       member[row][column]= 0;
                       }

                  }             

            }
```

Comment: must be array indexoutofbound exception

Answer (score 2):

You would be getting **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException**.

It is because you are accessing index [row][column] when you can legally only access row index from **0 to row-1** and column index from **0 to column-1**.

So, change `member[row][column]` to `member[i][j]` in the above code.

As i moves from 0 to row-1 and j moves from 0 to column-1, this error would not occur.

Comment: No its not an **OutOfBounds** exception, on the array instatiation it  tells me Syntax error " ; ", { expected after this token.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving value to same element on every iteration of loop change the initialization statement inside the loop

```
 public class Graph_arr
            {
              int row  = 6 ;
              int column = 6;
              int [][] member = new int [row][column];
              for(int i=0 ;i < row; i ++)
                  {
                  for (int j = 0 ; j < column ;j++)
                       {
                       member[i][j]= 0;
                       }

                  }             

            }
```